# Calling method_missing for undefined attributes in Rails after using "update" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, method-missing

Is there a short way for `obj.update(attr1: "something")` method to call `method_missing` instead of raising the error `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'attr1' for Obj.)`?

I am thinking about simply rescuing it and then mimicking/calling the method_missing, but this way feels too bulky.

Comment: what is the question here

Comment: The question is: when you call `obj.update(attr1: "something")`, it raises error `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'attr1' for Obj.)`. I want it to call `method_missing` instead, where I would specify the proper setter.

Comment: Hm. How could you call method_missing if method exists?

Comment: It doesn't, there is no `attr1=` method on this model. Maybe my description is a bit vague. What I want to do is to create dynamic setters, so when `attr1` is undefined, it would go to `method_missing` where I would write the code to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L53) (Rails 4.2) it seems that `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError` is raised when the model instance does not `respond_to?` to the given attribute setter. So what you have to do is **define a `method_missing` as well as `respond_to_missing?` in the model** for all your dynamic attributes. This is actually what you [always should do](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/always-define-respond-to-missing-when-overriding) when using `method_missing` anyway:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTES = [:attr1, :attr2]

  def method_missing(method_name, *arguments, &block)
    if DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTES.map { |attr| "#{attr}=" }.include?(method_name.to_s)
      puts "custom code for #{method_name} #{arguments.first.inspect}"
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to_missing?(method_name, include_private = false)
    DYNAMIC_ATTRIBUTES.map { |attr| "#{attr}=" }.include?(method_name.to_s) || super
  end

end
```

**Test** in Rails console:

```
Model.first.update(attr1: 'aa', attr2: 'bb')
# => custom code for attr1= "aa"
# => custom code for attr2= "bb"

Model.first.update(attr1: 'aa', attr2: 'bb', attr3: 'cc')
# => ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'attr3' for Model.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
  rescue_from ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError do |exception|
    raise NoMethodError
    # or however you want to hanle
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
begin
  obj.update(attr1: "something")
rescue Exception => ex
  if  ex.class == ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError
    method_missing
  else
    raise ex
  end
end
```